# Spring JPA share entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have Web application using Spring MVC and JPA (Hibernate is my JPA provider). Structure of the application is standard / normal Web application architecture like Controller > Service > Repository (where you can do normal CRUD operations on JPA entities).

I have a Service class say `A` which in turns calls other two services `B` and `C`. `A` starts the transaction; `B` and `C` both operates on one common entity (e.g. `Product`) along with other entities.

My requirement is: if `B` make some changes to `Product` entity (after getting it using `em.find`), when `C` invokes `em.find` on `Product` (same **ID**) `B` changes should be reflected, without persisting `B` changes to database. How to achieve that?

If I call `em.merge` from `B` it persists to the database. What I want is that `A` should only commit/rollback transaction as it started the transaction.

Comment: Can you expose your "service" class declarations? How are you managing transactions in between?

Comment: If this is all part of the same transaction then ServiceC will always "see" the updated entity. Is it getting the stale entity?

Comment: You're confused between executing SQL queries inside a transaction, and committing the transaction. C will see the changes made by B, since they both operate inside the same transaction. The changes made on the entity, whatever service makes these changes, are automatically written to the database when Hibernate considers it's necessary. And these changes are made permanent if and only if the transaction is committed. They're canceled if the transaction is rollbacked. If you don't even want changes to be written to the database, then don't modify the entity.